# how send data from infopath form to business data list web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, infopath

1. I have a table in my database including a large number of data
2. I define an external content type on it
3. I define two `operations`:

   - `read list` with two filters:

     1. `limit filter`
     2. filter on one of table column(`wildcard`)
   - `read item`.
4. I create an InfoPath list with one field to search in my external Content Type.

My Solution :

1. I add two web parts to my page: InfoPath webpart and Business data list.
2. I add a new `rule` for handle change event and for action use `send data to web part` in InfoPath form.
3. I add new connection `send Query values` to Business data list from InfoPath form.

Now when I change some item in the textbox of the InfoPath form, the page is refreshed and nothing is showed as result .

I use Business data item instead of Business data list, but can not send value to BD list from InfoPath form.

Any ideas?